# Connecting android with ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu

Is there a way to connect your PC with ubuntu 16.04 with your android device with version as low as 4.4.2 so that I could launch the app made on Android studio from my device? All the instructions I find only work for 6.0 or higher.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Android worked with Ubuntu even when I was on jellybean, and AFAIK situation has only improved with more recent Ubuntu versions. Have you tried any of the solutions? Which problems are you facing? Install adb and see whether it works out of the box, and if not try to find appropriate drivers.

Comment: Connect how? HTTP? What instruction? Did you try with other versions? Version doesn't matter for http ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device

Comment: adb is installed. I checked using the adb commands to see if devices were connected and no device was listed. SO, I am kind of confused what I am missing.

Comment: You need to enable developer mode in the device

Comment: Did that too. Thanks for the input guys.

Comment: My setup is Ubuntu 16.04 with a 4.4.2 device. What specifically is the problem, or at least what's your best guess at where things go wrong? Having the exact same setup, I can probably help.

Comment: It's just that I have done all the necessary installations and stuff but my phone still does not show up in the connected devices' list of Android Studio.